# Winforms C#: Get image from remote computer folder and load into DataTable's column

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a remote computer that stores a lot of images in a folder.

From my winforms c# app in .net 3.5, I would like to search for one image within remote computer folder and once found, store it in a Datatable's column. This search will be based on a file name that I will pass.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow below steps
 1. Create DirectoryInfo object and points to Remote computer via its shared path.
 2. Folder which needs to accessed must be shared.
 3. After creation of DirectoryInfo , search files inside that directory,.
 4. If image found, read its data and convert to bytes.
 5. Add bytes to column of DataTable.